# ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment - Error while running kafka 3.1.0 & java11 in windows

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to setup kafka 3.1.0 with java 11 on my local machine. However, while listing existing topics, I am getting timeout exception.

Steps followed:

Started zookeeper server:

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat config\\zookeeper.properties
```

Started kafka server:

```
kafka-server-start.bat config\\server.properties
```

Command to list topics:

```
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --list

Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics \[2022-02-19 20:11:37,239\] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

Comment: You're using the wrong port. Voting to close question as a typo

Answer (score 5):

Are you using port 2181 for Kafka? 2181 should be the port for the Zookeeper if I'm not wrong. Try the same but with the default port of Kafka, 9092.

Comment: Thanks, my issue resolved. Basically, I enabled listener in server.properties as listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092. Then while running list command changed port number to 9092 

C:\kafka_2.13-3.1.0>kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list  
first_topic  
C:\kafka_2.13-3.1.0>

Comment: cool, you can mark it as accepted answer so people will know it is solved

Comment: I already had`--bootstrap-server localhost:9092`, but started getting this out of nowhere. Restarting my Mac did it. Not sure what the actual issue was, but I had spent over an hour trying to figure it out. For those struggling and looking for a quick answer, try rebooting first before you go down the StackOverflow rabbit hole.